# How to reuse/get values ​from enum

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

I'm currently learning and trying to expand my knowledge of React and Typescript, so I apologize in advance for the explanations if they're not good.
In my react app I have created an enum that I am trying to reuse in 2 cases: First as a type and then to visualize the values, but I'm having difficulty with this and I'm not sure how or if I can do it the way I'm thinking.

This is part of my code: https://pastebin.com/9Y0fCVjS

```
export type InventoryGroup = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  status: InventoryStatus;
  statusText?: string;
};

export enum InventoryStatus {
  WAITING = 'Waiting',
  IN_PROGRESS = 'In progress',
  IMPORTED = 'Imported',
  FAILED = 'Failed',
}
 
const statusColumnBuilder = useCallback((data: InventoryGroup) => {
    // data?.status === 'IMPORTED' (for example)
    // and I was trying to do something similar InventoryStatus[data?.status]; but it didn't work and I'm wondering why
    const status = InventoryStatus[data?.status?.toString() as keyof typeof InventoryStatus];
    return <span title={data.statusText && data.statusText}>{status}</span>;
}, []);
```

As a response from a request, I get status, which is one of the enuma values: WAITING, FAILED etc.
What I want to do is in the place where I need to display the status use the values ​​from the enum.
My idea is to do something like this: `InventoryStatus[data?.status]`

data.status === IMPORTED (for example) but I need to show it as 'Imported', this is where I got the idea, can't I reuse the enum?

The only way I've been able to get it to work is like this:
`InventoryStatus[data?.status?.toString() as keyof typeof InventoryStatus];`

But I would be grateful if you could suggest me another solution, or a way to simplify it :)

Comment: Please include your code directly in the question as plaintext; external links to example code can sometimes be nice supplements but we can’t require people to navigate away from Stack Overflow to see the full question.

Answer (score 0):

`IMPORTED` by itself doesn't mean anything or have a value.

`data.status === InventoryStatus.IMPORTED ? // do something : // do something else` would be an example of using `InventoryStatus` correctly.

Assuming you've used `InventoryStatus` in sending the value of `data.status` as props, you don't need to do anything else. `data.status` will be a value in the enum.

So, if `data.status` is coming through as "IMPORTED" then chances are you've set that value in data, instead of setting `data.status` to `InventoryStatus.IMPORTED`

eg:

```
const data: InventoryGroup = {
   ...
   status: "IMPORTED" // wrong, and should fail type checking
   status: InventoryStatus.IMPORTED // correct
}

statusColumnBuilder(data);
```

Using your example above, imagine that `data.status` is equal to `InventoryStatus.IMPORTED`. That's the same as saying `data.status === "Imported"`.

For this reason the statement `InventoryStatus[data?.status]` won't work, as you're effectively asking for `InventoryStatus['Imported']` which doesn't exist.

Does that make sense? If not, I'll expand on the answer.

Comment: I think I understand your logic and example, thanks! The only thing that remains unclear to me is why the data.status I get is IMPORTED and not 'Imported'. All I do is just because I want to visualize the status as 'Imported'

Comment: @Sarah - I've added a bit of code that should clear that up. 